# how to drop columns in mysql table where the values are passed through array in php

Tags: php, sql

```
$que=mysql_query("select col_name from tbl_column_selected") or 
die(mysql_error());
while(list($row_info) = mysql_fetch_array($que)) { 
  $data_arr[] = $row_info;
}  

for($i=0; $i < count($data_arr); $i++) {
  $col = $data_arr[$i];
  mysqli_query($con,"ALTER TABLE tbl_display_selected_column ADD ".$col." 
 CHAR(50)");
}
for($j=0; $j<count($data_arr); $j++) {
  $res = $data_arr[$j];
  mysqli_query($con,"ALTER TABLE tbl_display_selected_column DROP ".$res."");
}
```

I can add columns to the table but i cannot drop the columns created. I have checked the columns are empty but still cannot drop.
please help with the code.

Comment: Please see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: this question needs more informations. For example: Do you get any kind of error message/exception? Does your user have permission to drop columns? Also what @MasivuyeCokile wrote.